# elasticsearch - aggregation stats on latest document of unique records

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

There are about 300,000 unique users/customers. We have one document each for every order placed, so we have several million documents.

each order document looks like this

```
{
   "customer_id" : 1001,
   "order_amount" : 15.00,
   "timestamp" : 1465450000, //epoch time when order was placed
}
```

I need the "Stats Aggregation" metrics on each unique customer records (customer_id) latest order i.e for each customer take the latest order amount and perform stats aggregation (ignoring older orders)

Is this possible in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly the following should work. Since we have access to the query we can do anything to limit the data set. In my example I simply said the timestamp >= 1365440000 :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                        "gte": 1365440000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "customers": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "customer_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "order_stats": {
                    "stats": {
                        "field": "order_amount"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
{
    "took": 32,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 8,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "customers": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
        {
            "key": 1001,
            "doc_count": 4,
            "order_stats": {
                "count": 4,
                "min": 13,
                "max": 15,
                "avg": 13.875,
                "sum": 55.5
            }
        },
        {
            "key": 1002,
            "doc_count": 4,
            "order_stats": {
                "count": 4,
                "min": 13.5,
                "max": 15.5,
                "avg": 14.625,
                "sum": 58.5
            }
          }
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does NOT work. You are using a hardcoded timestamp filter range. Thats not what I am looking for. The query needs to look at the latest document for each customer